Выравнивание в заголовке протокола прикладного уровня
Практикуюсь в сетевом программировании. Для интереса решил придумать простой протокол прикладного уровня, базирующийся на tcp/ip. Заголовок протокола содержит 3 поля: 2 поля по 4 байта для неких идентификаторов и одно поле на 2 байта для указания длины полезной нагрузки.
Вопрос №1: нужно ли добавить еще одно поле в заголовок для того, чтоб заголовок был кратен 4? Читал, что на некоторых архитектурах cpu переменная размером 2 байта будет автоматически выравнена по границе 4 байт.
Вопрос №2: Правильно ли я рассчитал максимальный размер полезной нагрузки?
Без дополнительного поля на 2 байта: 65535 - 60 (максимальный размер tcp заголовка) - 10 = 65 465 байт.
С дополнительным полем на 2 байта: 65535 - 60 - 12 = 65 463 байт.


я бы добавил (люблю круглые числа) 2) imho, правильно (странно, конечно, что создатели IP не стали в свое время жадничать и считать число 0 за истинный размер данных  в 1 байт...)


почитайте спецификации на SCTP - более гибкая вешь, или MODBAS - примитивная штука. PS: прикладные протоколы, на то и прикладные, что их к чему-то прикладывают. У Вас же протокол ради протокола.

@balbes я же в первых строчках написал, что практикуюсь. Так что да, это протокол ради протокола
